# Using complex conditional validation rule in FormRequest in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I am developing a Web application using Laravel. What I am doing now is creating a FirmRequest for the validation.

This is my FormRequest.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreVacancy extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required',
            'complex_field' => ...need complex conditional validation based on the type field
        ];
    }
}
```

If I did not use the FormRequest, I can create validator in the controller and set complex conditional validation rule like this.

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    //fields and rules
]);

$v->sometimes('reason', 'required|max:500', function ($input) {
    return $input->games >= 100;
});
```

But the issue is that I am not creating the Validator in the controller. But I am using the FormRequest. How can I achieve the same thing in the FormRequest?

Comment: try this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-closures

Comment: I still need to create $validator for that. I know how to use it in the Controller. How can I use that closure in the FormRequest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can manually adjust the rules depending on the input data:

```
class StoreVacancy extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        $reason = $this->request->get('reason'); // Get the input value
        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required',
            'type'  => 'required',
        ];

        // Check condition to apply proper rules
        if ($reason >= 100) {
            $rules['complex_field'] = 'required|max:500';
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Its not the same as **sometimes**, but it does the same job.

Answer (score 4):

Since 5.4 you can use the method "withValidator" inside your FormRequest:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

> This method receives the fully constructed validator, allowing you to call any of its methods before the validation rules are actually evaluated

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreVacancy extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->sometimes('reason', 'required|max:500', function ($input) {
            return $input->games >= 100;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer as gives a lot of flexibility by allowing the user full access to the input object so can check against any params and also add built in validation or custom ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the createDefaultValidator function in https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php. We will override that function and add our condition

```
    /**
     * Add Complex Conditional Validation to the validator instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Factory  $factory
     * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validator($factory)
    {
        $validator = $factory->make(
            $this->validationData(),
            $this->container->call([$this, 'rules']),
            $this->messages(),
            $this->attributes()
        );

        $validator->sometimes('reason', 'required|max:500', function ($input) {
            return $input->games >= 100;
        });

        return $validator;
    }
```